# The manager chooses 2 guests at random. Find the probability that they are both staying in the same room.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $25$ rooms in a hotel; $3$ with $0$ guests, $4$ with $1$ guest each, $12$ with $2$ guests each, $5$ with $3$ guests each and $1$ with $4$ guests.
Total rooms: $25$
Total guests: $47$

Q. The manager chooses $2$ guests at random. Find the probability that they are both staying in the same room.

I got

$$12\left(\frac{2}{47} \cdot \frac{1}{46}\right) + 5\left(\frac{3}{47} \cdot \frac{2}{46}\right) + 1\left(\frac{4}{47} \cdot \frac{3}{46}\right) = \frac{33}{1081}$$

Somebody explain this to me.

Comment: Show us how you arrived at that number, then we can see what we need to explain.

Comment: 12(2/47*1/26) + 5(3/47*2/46) + 1(4/47*3/46) = 216/7567

Comment: I assume you meant to write $\frac{1}{46}$ in the first parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 
$$\binom{47}{2}$$
ways for the manager to select two of the forty-seven guests in the hotel.

In order to select two guests from the same room, the manager must select both guests from a room with two people or two of the three guests in a room with three people or two of the four guests in a room with four people.  Since there are $12$ rooms with two people, $5$ rooms with three people, and one room with four people, the manager can do this in 
$$12\binom{2}{2} + 5\binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{2}$$
ways.

Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{12\dbinom{2}{2} + 5\dbinom{3}{2} + \dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{47}{2}}$$

**Note:**  I assume you meant to write 
$$12\left(\frac{2}{47} \cdot \frac{1}{\color{red}{46}}\right) + 5\left(\frac{3}{47} \cdot \frac{2}{46}\right) + 1\left(\frac{4}{47} \cdot \frac{3}{46}\right)$$
in which case you would have obtained the correct probability.

Comment: Yeah I meant 46.

Comment: Wait, I got it right?  Damn. I don't even know what I did. Thanks btw.

Comment: I would upvote your answer but I'm a new user, so I can't yet.

Comment: Justification:  There are $47 \cdot 46$ ways for the manager to make an ordered selection of two guests.  In the $12$ rooms with $2$ people, there are $2 \cdot 1 = 2$ ways for the manager to make an ordered selection of both guests.  In the $5$ rooms with three people, there are $3 \cdot 2$ ways for the manager to make an ordered selection of two guests.  In the room with four people, there are $4 \cdot 3$ ways for the manager to make an ordered selection with two guests.  Hence, there are $$12 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 + 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$$ favorable selections.